# How to dynamically append elements to ListModel from exterior scope

Tags: qt, qml

Suppose I had the `Component`

```
Component {
  id: myComp1

  Item {
    id: item

    ListView {
      id: listView
      model : ListModel { id: listModel } 
      delegate : RowLayout { /* display model data*/ } 
      
      Component.onCompleted {
        // get data from server ... 
        model.append(dataFromServer)
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Then I have a second `Component`, which is another page in the stack, and I want to use this component to update `mycomp1`, i.e:

```
Component {
  id: myComp2
  Button {
    onClicked: { 
      myComp1.item.listView.listModel.append(someNewData) // want to be able to do this
    }  
  }
}
```

And these components are tied together in a `StackView`

Now, this doesnt seem to work since `myComp2` cant seem to access the necessary scope to update the model of `myComp1`. Is there any way around this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `Component` is like a type declaration. It does not define an instance of an object, so you cannot access its members.

You could pull the ListModel outside of that `Component` so that both Components can access it.

```
ListModel {
    id: listModel
}

Component {
    id: comp1
    ListView { model: listModel }
}

Component {
    id: comp2
    Button {
        onClicked: { listModel.append(someNewData) }
    }
}
```